# How to overwrite old entry with newer one in mysql table?

Tags: java, mysql, web-services, sql-insert

I'm developing a webservice using JSON that inserts the email of g+ user(once the user chooses to login to my app through google sign-in).
I don't want my webservice to enter multiple entries for the same user into my table.
I want to overwrite the old entry of email with the newer one.
what should I do?

**Edit 1:**
    //setGplusEmail

```
public ArrayList<Status> setEmail(Connection con,String gplusMail) throws SQLException
{
    ArrayList<Status> gplusUserList = new ArrayList<Status>();
    //con.setAutoCommit(false);
    String sql = "INSERT INTO gpluslogin (gmail) VALUES ('"+gplusMail+"')";
    String sql1 = "INSERT INTO gpluslogin (gmail) VALUES ('"+gplusMail+"') ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE (gmail = '"+gplusMail+"')";


    PreparedStatement stmt = con.prepareStatement(sql);
    PreparedStatement stmt1 = con.prepareStatement(sql1);

    try{
        stmt.executeUpdate();
        stmt1.executeUpdate();
    }catch(Exception e){

    }


    Status s = new Status();
    s.setStatus("Successfully Inserted...");
    gplusUserList.add(s);

    return gplusUserList;
}
```

Is this the right way to execute?

Comment: [`INSERT ... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/insert-on-duplicate.html)

Comment: @khelwood so i should just use one query or two?? i mean i m first inserting  the mail using first insert query and then i have to use the query you mentioned above to overwrite the older mail entry? i m new to sql..

Comment: you can simply use update command for that

Comment: `INSERT` will insert a new row. `UPDATE` will update an existing row. `INSERT ... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE` will insert the row if there is not a clash, and update the clashing row if there is clash.

Comment: @khelwood thanks for the help..i had to use both the queries to fetch the emails with no duplicate entries.

Comment: @whenthemorningcomes : to use insert....on duplicate...you need to create unique key on email else it will not work.

Comment: I did! and it works thanks for the suggestions!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After creating unique key on gmail column you can use any one statement out of below 2-

```
REPLACE INTO gpluslogin (gmail) VALUES('abc@gmail.com');

OR

INSERT INTO gpluslogin (gmail) VALUES('abc@gmail.com') ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE gmail='abc@gmail.com';
```

Answer (score 1):

```
UPDATE user_table SET email=$newemail WHERE userID = $userID
```